# My cronjob isn't working?

Tags: php, cron

Maybe a silly question, but I'm trying to get a cronjob to work. Although this could be a question for serverfault I think its also a SO-question.

Anyway:
I have set up a cronjob to be executed everey 1 minute of every hour, day (number), day (name) and month. The given command is: /home/easybr01/domains/easybranding.nl/public_html/cronjobs/test.php

Which is nothing more than a file with a simpe php function `mail(to, subj, content, hdrs)` to test if it works... but the mails never come in.. and they're not in a spam folder eighter..

Does someone know what's wrong?? I figured this should be pretty straight forward...

Comment: Basic debugging first. Is the cron job executed at all? (e.g. try writing the current time into a temporary file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should indicate ${PATH_TO_PHP} into the cronjob, like :-

```
* * * * * ${PATH_TO_PHP} /home/easybr01/domains/easybranding.nl/public_html/cronjobs/test.php
```

Alternatively, you can make the script executable (ex. mod 744),
and place `#!${PATH_TO_PHP}` into first line of your PHP script, like :-

```
#!${PATH_TO_PHP}
<?php
// remanding code
?>
```

Comment: I've changed the chmod and added the path to PHP, waiting a minute now to see the effect.

Comment: Thankyou it worked now! And after many many times I started realized another thing I did wrong.. I put a 1 instead of a * in the minute field... which obviously means it should only execute the job every 1st minute of an hour. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

For starters, you need to run the PHP command-line interpreter, not just point to a PHP file.  If you're giving a command to cron, it needs the whole command.

Comment: Okay.. I didn't knew that, obviously.. ;) Thank you.